# How to use value of a certain cell as the row number in a cell reference?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

`Cell 1` references to `Cell 2 (=ODOC!A11)` which is a number `x` (1,2,3,...) 
`Cell 3` needs to refer to `cell 4 (=OTAB!A"x")`. So the row needs to change according to the number `x`.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Non-volatile (prefered method):

```
=INDEX(OTAB!A:A,CELL1)
```

Or volatile:

```
=INDIRECT("OTAB!A"&CELL1)
```

You can also directly reference Cell 2.

```
=INDEX(OTAB!A:A,ODOC!A11)
```

Comment: Only the    =INDIRECT("OTAB!A"&B2) is working the other two =INDEX(OTAB!A:A,B2) and =INDEX(OTAB!A:A,ODOC!A11) give error: There's a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula?
When the first character is an equal (=) or minus (-) sign, Excel thinks it's a formula:

Comment: @jbmans does your version of Excel use `;` as the delimiter instead of the `,`?